# Updating an MVC 5 Partial View using Ajax on some control event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

As the title states, I wanted to know if there's a nice way to update a partial view using ajax on some control event.

For example, if I have a div with the overflow property set to scroll, I want to update the div with more values as soon as the scroll has reached the bottom.

Comment: Your problem here is _when_ to make your AJAX request. Search for "infinite scroll" and you'll find many useful resources.

Comment: see this post:http://developmentpassion.blogspot.com/2013/12/infinite-scroll-paging-in-aspnet-mvc-4.html

Comment: That's exactly what I've been searching for. Thanks a lot.